# Show input suggestions INSIDE input box

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to show suggestions like this inside of `<input>`:

[image: like this]

I am using React & Material-UI. I've tried using absolute positioning, but that leads to pixel-impefect calculations of offset. How else can I achieve this? Is there a way I can force placeholder to remain even when input is non-empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an input with span absolutely positioned:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="input" type="text">
  <span class="placeholder"></span>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/kah8130m/1/

Answer (score 0):

In Reactjs you can use "downshift" library to create an autocomplete input box. The library provides a set of hooks and components for building simple, flexible, WAI-ARIA compliant input enhancements.